# Trying to understand recursively finding minimum value

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

What I'm trying to do, is to find the local minima in a random row of an image (done), then find the local minima in that list.
I've written the following code to use a function to find the minimum values in a 1-d array:

```
import numpy as np
values = []
pixels = []

def find_minima(array):
    '''
    Takes a 1-d array as an argument, and returns a list of the
    minimum values of the array, and the pixels at which the
    minima occur
    '''
#   Find local minimum, and add to list of minimum-valued pixels
    for i in range(1, len(array)-1):
        if array[i-1] > array[i]:
            if array[i+1] > array[i]:
                values.append(array[i])
                pixels.append([i])
        else:
            continue
    return (values, pixels)


#   Generate a random image
np.random.seed(seed=128)
side = 15
img = np.random.rand(side, side)

height = img.shape[0]                #   Inspect height of image

#   Select row at random
index = np.random.randint(0, height)
row = img[index]


minimum_values, minimum_pixels = find_minima(row)
global_minimum_values, global_minimum_pixels = find_minima(minimum_values)
```

The program works fine, up until I try to pass the list of `minimum_values` already found, back into the function to find the minima in that list.
I'm expecting that the variable values would be:

```
minimum_values = [0.2274, 0.6910, 0.2715, 0.3075]
minimum_pixels = [[1], [3], [7], [11]]
global_minimum_values = [0.2715]
global_minimum_pixels = [2]
```

but instead, the program just tacks the global minima onto the original list, so that they're all the same:

```
minimum_values = [0.2274, 0.6910, 0.2715, 0.3075, 0.2715]
minimum_pixels = [[1], [3], [7], [11], [2]]
global_minimum_values = [0.2274, 0.6910, 0.2715, 0.3075, 0.2715]
global_minimum_pixels = [[1], [3], [7], [11], [2]]
```

How can I change the code to produce my desired output?
Note: There are probably easier ways to do this, but this way fits best with the other processing I need to do, so I want to understand why this code in particular doesn't behave as I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are tracking your minima by reference to a global variable, `values`.  On your first pass through, when you call `find_minima` with `row`, on each iteration, you append to the global `values` variable.

The problem comes on your second pass through.  You've returned `values` in the first iteration, which is not a new list, but a reference to the global variable, which still has all your old values in it.

Instead, you should move `values = []` to the inside of your function, and return it at the end.  This way, on each call, you get a new list, and don't mutate the same global list.